# Why equation (5) is equal to equation (6)?

Tags: math, statistics

I found this material online, I do not understand why equation (5) is 
equal to equation (6)? How to deduct?

Given a dictionary D, a vector x has sparsity s if it can
be written exactly as a linear combination of s columns of
D. An important result that underlies all Sparse representation 
classification frameworks is the guarantee provided by the sparse 
recovery result that for a feature vector x with sparsity bounded 
from above by a constant depending on D, x can be recovered by
[image]

Comment: What does this have to do with MATLAB?

Comment: @excaza, the code for the equation is written by using Matlab

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics, not about programming.

Comment: Equation (6) expresses equation (5) in terms of an L2-norm with a Lagrange multiplier to include the constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an example of a Lagrange multiplier, and the two equations are not equivalent. However, the paper doesn't claim this: the text states that formula (5) is "modified" to get formula (6).

Using a Lagrange multiplier would lead to a coupled system of two equations. Note how formula (6) doesn't exactly enforce the constraint `Dc=x`, it only minimizes its residual. That's not the same thing. The solution `c` of (6) will typically not satisfy `Dc=x`, whereas the solution `c` of (5) always has to satisfy it by definition.

What (6) actually does is express the constraint using a penalty term. The parameter `lambda` expresses how much emphasis is put on minimizing the l1-norm of c versus minimizing the residual of the constraint `x - Dc`.

So, (5) puts a hard constraint on the permitted values `c`, whereas (6) basically says, "I've got these two things I'd both like to be somewhat small... find me a good compromise."

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on the [Lagrange multiplier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier). It's an easy way to maximize or minimize a function that must at the same fulfil equality constraints (not inequalities).

Comment: can you give me the detailed deduct process?

Comment: This is actually wrong, this is not using a Langrange multiplier, it's just a penalty formulation. The two formulas aren't equivalent either.

Comment: @cfh, you mean the equation (5) is not equal to equation (6)? This comes from a good paper.

Comment: @Angelababy: It's not a mistake in the paper. They claim that formula (5) is "modified" to get formula (6), and indeed they are not equivalent. They will typically lead to "similar" solutions `c`, but not identical ones.

Comment: @cfh. Oh, I see! the solution solved by equation (6) is better than  or worse than the solution solved by equation (5) ?

Comment: @Angelababy: How do you define "better" or "worse"? I've posted an answer now, maybe it will make it a bit clearer.